# How to extract part of the line and append it to the end of line in VIM with regex?

Tags: vim

I have a file with a number of urls in the form:

http://www.edu-factory.org/wp/about/

I'd like to extract the sitehost of the url and append it to the end of the line:

http://www.edu-factory.org/wp/about/ www.edu-factory.org

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that:

```
:s:\(.*//\)\([^/]*\)\(/.*\):\1\2\3 \2:
```

Explanation:

- `:s:` - Using substitution
- `\(.*//\)` - Capture the part up to the double slash (group 1)
- `\([^/]*\)` - Capture everything that's not a slash (group 2)
- `\(/.*\)` - Capture the first single slash and everything after it (group 3)
- `:\1\2\3 \2:` - Output groups 1, 2 and 3 followed by a space and group 2 again

**Edit:**

You could sorten that to:

```
:s:\(.*//\)\([^/]*\)\(/.*\):& \2:
```

The ampersand outputs the whole matched string which includes the whole line since the regex begins and ends with `.*`. You could use `\0` instead of the ampersand.

Comment: And is there an output group that contains the whole line in which there was a match?

Comment: @sumek: Please see my edited answer.